# Switch between two digital signals with no microcontroller

Tags: arduino, switches, signal-processing, decoder

I'd like to use an Arduino to send wirelessy (RF 433MHz, probably) two different digital signals to pilot two different relays (later they will be much more).

I know probably this is something very basic but is there a way to use just one RF and switch between two digital signals without the need of another microcontroller on the receiver? If so, which ICs do I need (demux, maybe)?

Very quick schematic, U1 is what I'm looking for

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpAhWi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A very dummy truth table could be this one:

SIG1 | Y1 | Y2

NONE |    GND  |      GND|

01  |     ON   |      GND|

10  |     GND |       ON |

Thank you for your help,

Comment: How do you plan to vary SIG1 in order to switch between the relays?

Comment: Is at any time only one relay activated or do you actually need a signal to turn a relay on and a signal to turn it off? Can you make a list of (abstract) signals vs. relay state, a truth table?

Comment: EMFields Still need to clarify that, probably something dummy like 00 and 01 will work

@jippie just one relay at time. When there is no signal, everything should be off. This means that Y1 and Y2 have to be grounded.

Comment: If you want three choices: 1) Both relays off, 2) Relay 1 on and relay 2 off, 3) Relay 2 on and relay 1 off, then you'll need a device with either two inputs or a single input which can decode between three states in order for it to decide what to do.  If your decoder has only one input, as you've shown, then you could use no input to have both relays off, 2kHz to turn relay 1 on and relay 2 off, and some other frequency to turn relay 2 on and relay 1 off.  For starters, why don't you tell us where that 2kHz is coming from?

Comment: @EMFields thank you for your help.No sorry, the 2kHz it's just random (like I said, the schematic was very quick :) ). Anyway, I can't modify the frequency, since I'm receiving the data from an Arduino through a 433MHz RF receiver (or probably an nRF24L01, still need to evaluate pros/cons) . What I can do is change the message sent and act accordingly. If, dummy example, I'm sending 01, I want relay1 ON, otherwise if it is 10 then Relay2 is ON. Assume U1 as a blackbox, it can also be a combination of multiple devices in order to obtain the above results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://strobotix.com/documents/RF_Based_Wireless_Remote.pdf) is probably what you could use. It's 4 channels so it more than meets your needs: -

[image]

And [here's](http://wiguna149.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/using-wireless-rf-module-with-ht12-encoder-and-decoder/) a better link to an rf module set

Comment: Thank you Andy, this looks EXACTLY what I was looking for! Sadly, it's a bit more expensive than I thought (8-10EUR for each tx/rx).

Just one more question, if you are familiar with it: what if I us an nRF24L01 instead of 433MHz RF? Is it still doable without a microcontroller on the receiver? what do I have to take care of? Many Thanks =)

Comment: I've never used it dude, sorry.

Comment: @mrflo No, that won't work. The nRF24L01 needs a microcontroller to drive it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a 2:1 [digital multiplexer](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html).

You should be able to [find a product](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv130=181&pv591=1&FV=fff40027%2Cfff802b3&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500) which will run at 433MHz.

Comment: Thank you hk! What happens though when there is no signal SIG1? one of the two inputs is kept connected or they are grounded?

Answer (score 0):

If, instead of 2kHz, you could send - say 8 bit bytes continuously - then you could use the absence of data out of the receiver, 0x00, to signify both relays OFF, 0xf0 to signify relay 1 ON, and 0Xff to signify relay 2 ON. Or, any other pattern easy to decode.

A second approach, if you can't send data continuously (or reliably over the desired ON period of the relays) might be to use the data decoders to drive one-shots which in turn would drive latching relays.

Seems like it would be smaller-faster-better-cheaper, though, to use a simple MCU on the receiver's output to do the job.